# Как юридически оформить право владения программным продуктом 50/50 без ООО?

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Написали с другом Android приложение, хотим юридически оформить право владения 50/50, чтоб потом можно было без проблем продать его, читали про ООО но это слишком муторно  может что проще есть? Мы оба физлица. Может кто сталкивался подскажет?

Comment: Муторно потом будет судиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свое время (году так 2002) я и два моих партнёра просто зарегистрировали программный продукт у нотариуса (в соотношении 50/30/20). Когда передавали по роялти за границу, данный документ у нас приняли без каких-то оговорок, по нему же оформили доли в роялти.

Впрочем, прошло уже больше 12 лет (с момента заключения роялти), могло многое поменяться в законах. Я бы просто позвонил нескольким нотариусам и узнал, занимаются ли они подобным.